# How to make execution of a scheduled task invisible in Windows?

Tags: php, windows

I have a piece of PHP code running on Windows that I have scheduled to run after every hour using Windows Task Scheduler. The problem is that the command line opens up everytime the code is run, whereas I was the execution to happen invisibly. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Try this:
http://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.php.net/install.windows.manual

```
The PHP package structure and content
[...]
|-php-win.exe                -- executes scripts without an opened command prompt
```

So, instead of php.exe use php-win.exe